# Laravel - PHPUnit - Model Factory - Many to Many relationships

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit, many-to-many, factory

Consider the following entites

```
Students
Subjects
Exams
```

and following relationships

```
Student belongsToMany Subjects (Many-to-Many)
Student hasMany Exams

Subject belongsToMany Students (Many-to-Many)
Subject hasMany Exams

Exam belongsTo Student
Exam belongsTo Subject
```

So I am writing some test cases for the models and its relationships using ModelFactory (I am new to unit testing). I need to test a case where the Student and Subject for a Exam is related. So I did the following in test and factory.

Test

```
public function testStudentAndSubjectIsRelated()
{
    $exam = factory(Exam::class)->create();

    // We need to know whether the student and subject is related

    $this->assertTrue($exam->student->subjects()->pluck('id')->contains($exam->student_id));

    // And viceversa
    $this->assertTrue($exam->subject->students()->pluck('id')->contains($exam->subject_id));
}
```

Factory

```
$factory->define(App\Exam::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'student_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Student::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'subject_id' => function ($exam) {
            $subject = factory(App\Subject::class)->create();

            $student = App\Student::find($exam['student_id']);

            $subject->students()->save($student);

            return $subject->id;
        },

        ....
    ];
});
```

Is this the right way of doing it?